# How to detect tap begin with Long press?

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to detect 3 actions, "Tap begin", "Long press begin", "Long press ended". I want to detect "Tap begin" regardless of detection long tap (i.e. every time when touch the screen, detect "Tap begin") and detect "Tap begin" followed by "long press begin" in case keep touching.

Below code enables to detect "Tap begin" only in case "Long tap" is not detected.

```
    let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.Long(_:)))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 3  
    longPressGesture.allowableMovement = 30    

    let shortPressGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.Tap(_:)))

    touchView.addGestureRecognizer(shortPressGesture)
    touchView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

}

@objc func Long(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began) {
    print("Long tap begin")
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended) {
    print("Long tap ended")
    }
}

@objc func Tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Tap begin")
}
```

Comment: can't you initiate a timer on press and evaluate it on release?

Answer (score 1):

You need to conform to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

and then implement the `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith` function to allow your two gesture recognisers to work at the same time.

Also I think you're actually wanting to use two UILongPressGesutureRecognizers as taps are detected on touch up.

```
  @objc func Long(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began) {
      print("Long tap begin")
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended) {
      print("Long tap ended")
    }
  }

  @objc func Tap(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began) {
      print("Tap begin")
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended) {
      print("Tap ended")
    }
  }

  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer == longPressGesture && otherGestureRecognizer == shortPressGesture {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
```

Finally don't forget to set the delegates of the gesture recognisers to self

```
tapPressGesture.delegate = self
shortPressGesture.delegate = self
```

Comment: This answer is almost correct, to complement this answer, you will need to have two `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`s. The first one is set with a `minimumPressDuration` of X seconds, where you'll observe the `began` state to trigger the long press, as well as `ended` and `cancelled` to trigger the end of the gesture. 

The trick is to have the second `UILongPressGestureRecognizers` have a `minimumPressDuration` of zero, and observe this gesture's `began` state, triggered immediately on "touch down".

Comment: As an added, bonus comment, you can also observe the first gesture's `changed` state to track how the gesture's location changes in the view, effectively making this gesture act like a UIPanGestureRecognizer. With this setup you'll be able to track touch down, long press, movement and end of the gesture. Powerful stuff.